# Editing closed questions to try to reopen when there are answers

Tags: discussion, editing, closed-questions

Based on [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/980/is-mi-yodeya-helpful). It's pretty easy to take out the opinion-based portion and rephrase it to be "Is Mi Yodeya considered bitul Torah when you can go get a sefer?" while leaving out the opinion-based aspect of "Is Mi Yodeya helpful when you can go grab a Sefer?"

Here's the thing: there are actually answers.

So is it wrong to edit the post when it'll invalidate the answers for the sake of reopening the question?

(Yes, I'm aware that the post is really old and probably nobody cares. That's not the point.)

Comment: Very similar concern: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3924/3

Comment: How is your question here different from http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1231?

Comment: @msh210 This is different because it's focusing on a closed question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, it's not clear to me from the question that that's the focus here.

Comment: @msh210 It's in the title. I guess the body should be edited to match.

Comment: @msh210 Yes my point was that it's a closed question that I'm trying to get reopened. I edited it to make it clearer, but I assumed from the linked question that it was clear enough in my original version.

Comment: @IsaacMoses See my comment to msh.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that there's little value in rescuing an old question that was closed for soliciting opinions, having a bunch of opinion-based answers on it. It would be much cleaner, if you're interested in answers to the objective alternative, to post the objective alternative as a new question, written well and carefully to solicit objective answers.

Comment: I understand that it was an old question. I was using it as an example, not as a limitation. Pretend that the question's a week old. Would that change your opinion?